# Apache Airflow running RBAC on LDAP

Tags: ldap, airflow

I am trying to make **Airflow[1.10.7]** work with **rbac**(Role Based Access Control) using **LDAP** login.
When my airflow.cfg file has `rbac = False` setting, I am able to login to Webserver using ldap credentials without a problem.

However when I set `rbac = True` in the config file, it seems like the ldap authentication gets automatically turned off and switches to regular password authentication managed by FlaskAppBuilder.

Is this a feature, or am I doing something wrong? Anyone experienced it/made it work?

Thanks for any help!